# override Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, overrides, newsletter

in My/Stuff/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <newsletter>
            <rewrite>
                <subscriber>My_Stuff_Model_Subscriber</subscriber>
            </rewrite>
        </newsletter>
    </models>
 (...)
```

in My/Stuff/Model/Subscriber.php

```
class My_Stuff_Model_Subscriber extends Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber {

    public function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
    {
        Mage::Log('My_Stuff_Model_Subscriber::sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()');
    }
}
```

Mail was send but why is `sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()` not triggered?

My workaround is to copy Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber to local and that works but override should be cleaner.

Comment: Please double, no triple check if the model is not overwritten by another extension already. Happened to me once, spent an hour 'debugging' to find out some obscure, small extension was already messing with it

Comment: @SanderMangel Thanks, I didn't know that could be a problem. Is there an easy way to check this? What can I do if another model is messing with it?

Comment: @PiTheNumber You can use n98-magerun for this, if you don't have it. then you can easily install it from http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/47974204176/introduction-to-n98-magerun

Comment: Trey and search in the `community` and `local` codepool directories for the `<newsletter>` tag. That should work pretty well

Comment: Is your extension shown update System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced? If not could you please post your complete xml files.

Comment: Create a php script: test.php (in document root) and do a `Mage::app()` then `$model = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber'); echo get_class($model);` to check if your rewrite works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever I am dealing with overrides not working I do the following to check.

1. Validate that my extension appears in the admin list under:

   `System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`
2. Temporarily add the overridden class in the index.php and echo out it's class

   `var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')));`
3. Double check that you are using the correct code pool. Validate that if you are using the codePool local that your class is actually in local.